# JavaFX - Which method of event listener is more efficient?

Tags: java, javafx

I just started using event listener in JavaFX . I stumbled upon two methods for the same purpose. Any advantage of one or the other?

```
 test1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    System.out.print("PPT");
            }
        });
```

and

```
    test1 .selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov,
            Boolean old_val, Boolean new_val) {
            log("ggggggg");
        }
    });
```

Also `test1` is the name of the checkbox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference in efficiency between the two approaches is going to be essentially negligible - just choose the approach which is most appropriate and easiest to understand for your application functionality.

Comment: Can you also explain their main difference? Thanks for your reply btw :)

Comment: The main difference is that the listener for the action event will only be notified by a user action on the checkbox. The listener on the `selectedProperty()` will be notified any time the property changes. So if you programmatically call `test1.setSelected(! test1.isSelected());`, the `ChangeListener` will be notified, but the `EventHandler` will not.